# What plant is this magenta berry like shrub?

Tags: identification, shrubs, berries

Seattle, zone 7 I believe, has things that looks like berries year round.

About 4-5 ft tall and grows outward like a crepe mrtyle.

Thanks[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is *[Callicarpa americana](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callicarpa_americana)*, common name Beautyberry, a deciduous shrub native to the southern United States. The berries appear in late summer/fall and are attractive to birds and deer.

Comment: Often called "American" beauty berry. It can be invasive, but colorful. Deer do not care for the branches and foliage so in our area of the Piney Woods ( E TX ) it is the dominant understory shrub.

Comment: I like calling it "magenta" color , more exotic..